# Conditional formatting with style set outside of the rule

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to have a conditional formatting rule that is entirely driven from values in a sheet.

For example I want to have a table like

```
Lower Bound | Upper Bound | Colour
      0     |   10        | #000055
      11    |   20        | #0000FF
```

The table sets the background colour of a cell depending on the cells value.

I can get the conditional format to reference the upper and lower bounds, but I can't figure out how to get the style that is applied by the conditional formatting to be driven by a cell.

The reasoning behind this is so I don't have to change a whole host of conditional formats when I want to change the colours. Am I just trying to do too much?

Comment: Do you vba?  This might be easier in a macro.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is to do an exhaustive table for every combination you want, then "flag" the particular combination that you want to have currently active. I'll think on this problem some more.

Comment: You're going to want to use VBA for this - Excel natively doesn't seem to have a good way of parsing hex into a color without going through VBA. Seems like it'll be fairly simple to do inside of VBA

Comment: Alright - was avoiding VBA because the additional pain it adds when sharing the excel file.